# Error al cargar componente ANGULAR ERROR NG8001 : 'app-curso' is a not known element

Tags: angular, angular9

Bueno recien estoy empezando a aprender angular pero al hacer esta cosa tan sencilla me tira error.
La estructura de mi proyecto es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo  header.component.ts creo el selector: "app-curso"

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'app-curso',
    template:'<p>nueva etiqueta<p>'
})
export class HeaderComponent
{

}
```

En el archivo app.module.ts hago la respectiva importacion

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HeaderComponent} from './components/header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Y por ultimo en el archivo app.component.html llamo a las etiqueta  creada en el selector

```html
<h1>Hola mundo</h1>
<app-curso></app-curso>
```

Algo sencillo pero tira el siguiente error en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que estoy haciendo mal?
PD: disculpe si no me explique bien recien empeze a llevar el curso de angular

Comment: ¿Ese error te aparece cuando compilas el proyecto? `ng build`.

Comment: Utilizar ng serve - o para compilarlo

Comment: A efectos prácticos es lo mismo, `ng serve` va compilando con detección de cambios.

Comment: Si pero mi problemas no es ese, si no que no me reconoce la  etiqueta  'app-curso'  que lo defini en el selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Para el servidor local desde la consola (Ctrl + C).
- Lanza del nuevo `ng serve`

Tu código está bien, el compilador se ha quedado bloqueado.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono

Comment: de nada :) me alegro !!